# Crystal Reports command not working

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report connected to a table with a command which has parameters, this command query is working

```
SELECT 
    date1,  
    car_num, 
    ar_dromologiou, 
    Sum(kilomtres) As ksum, 
    sum(posostita_ltitra) as sumpos, 
    sum(shmaia) as sumkom, 
    sum(sinokomsim) AS x3
FROM 
    Table_1 
WHERE 
    date1 BETWEEN {?d1} AND {?d2} 
GROUP BY 
    date1, 
    car_num, 
    ar_dromologiou;
```

this doesn't work

```
SELECT 
    date1,  
    car_num, 
    ar_dromologiou, 
    Sum(kilomtres) As ksum, 
    sum(posostita_ltitra) as sumpos, 
    sum(shmaia) as sumkom, 
    sum(sinokomsim) AS x3 
FROM
    Table_1 
WHERE 
    car_num LIKE {?c1} AND 
    date1 BETWEEN {?d1} AND {?d2} 
GROUP BY 
    date1, 
    car_num, 
    ar_dromologiou;
```

Where is the fault?

Comment: When you say that the second query "doesn't work", what do you mean? Does it produce the wrong data? Does it return no data? Does the database return an error? Does Crystal Reports fail? What happens?

Comment: The only difference seems to be `car_num LIKE {?c1}`. Is car_num a text or implicitly convertible? Is your search pattern in `{?c1}` correct?

Comment: what error does it throw? what exactly means by not working?

Comment: Change into this car_num LIKE '%' + {?c1} +  '%'

Comment: thank you didn't receive email with your comments car_num is string and 2 irher parameters are date-time it produces no data.

Comment: I will try mahendra's suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the answers , I found that the values where in non english characters and crystal Reports wants some Extra configuration for this, didn't find yet but when I insert a record with english characters and in the parameter input english chars it showed the record, so something about the character encoding.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in your where clause where you compare `car_num`.

If you pass in your parameter `{?c1}` and it doesn't include any wildcard charaters like `%` or `_` you will only get *exact* matches.

Use wildcard characters appropriate for your use case, e.g.

```
WHERE 
    car_num LIKE {?c1} + '%' AND 
    date1 BETWEEN {?d1} AND {?d2}
```

This will match all rows where `car_num` starts with the value of your parameter `{?c1}`.

You may want to have a look at the documentation for the [LIKE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql) operator.